# Using Google Drive through an Android app

Tags: java, android

Maybe you can help me with an idea for an app I'm making these days (Android).

I need that one kind of user, let's call it "manager", will be able to upload documents in Word format. The other users will have it sent to them automatically, and they will be able to add comments for the doc (every user sees only his comments). This is the idea in general.

So far:
I thought to use Google Drive to store the documents because it had everything I wanted (read only mode and an option to add comments).

I wanted to have a web view, that will load the doc. If I load the same doc for everyone (in read-only mode), their comments will be public, but I want them to be private. By adding "copy" to the doc web address, I can force the user to duplicate the doc to his drive account.
Two problems with this idea:

1. Now the receiver can edit the file (I want it to be read-only) because it was duplicated.
2. The user has to log into his Google account every time. And I can't log him in programmatically.

What about the Drive API (to solve problem #2 - the main problem)? The problem with it is that the documents are printed without their design (font size, colours, etc.), and I haven't found a way to print the comments.

So, I'm very confused. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know may be U will not like it. When user write comments why can you just keep their comments in DB (for example FireBase) and when u gonna print it just past it in to the document with nice design( "Blablablabla"(John)). Bout second question: there should be state when you can keep user logged in after first login.

Comment: @Kyrmyzyanik How can I paste comments in to the document, while keeping them private?

Comment: After the users comments system will create new document and put there all that comments and only manager will be able to see it. Means manager upload document==> every user will write there is comments(to their own (copy) document) ==>allt hese comments will be kept in DB ==>system will take that comment put them to the document which will be visibile only to the manager.

p.s It is just my idea and it is not perfect. But if I do may be I have should follow this sctructure.